# What could cause heap corruption?

Tags: crash, diagnostic

Preamble: I would assume that this is just a bug, but I've been having some mysterious problems with this machine, so this question is (partly) an attempt to rule out hardware as a likely cause.

I've been having problems with a particular application (Elder Scrolls Online) that I haven't had before, and I'm curious if it could indicate a problem with my machine. It's crashed (AppCrash) a half-dozen times (more than an hour apart, on multiple days) with no discernible cause. Checking the Event Viewer shows "exception code 0xc0000374" for most of them, which indicates some degree of heap corruption. Others are 0x80000003, which is some kind of very old Dr. Watson code, that doesn't seem to be valid anymore.

Ignoring the history of this machine, I'd chalk this up to a bad update that'll get fixed in a few months. Unfortunately, the problems that I've had with this machine before have been memory related, and I've not fully identified/reconciled them.

So, is there any kind of diagnostic I can do to determine what is causing ESO.exe to have this problem? It seems like there might be a driver involved somewhere, or maybe it really is a hardware problem. I've looked into AppVerifier, but I don't have a debugger, so I can't really see the results.

Suggestions?

Comment: What could cause heap corruption, a memory problem, pretty much the only possible cause.

Comment: It's the "pretty much" that I'm worried about ;-) I've replaced literally every electrical component in the machine, except the (AMD) processor, and I'm still having the same sorts of "memory related" issues. It's becoming more and more apparent that the memory controller is bad, but I'm trying really hard to avoid a $200 diagnosis (replacing the CPU). Incidentally, I've NEVER had MemTest show any faults at all.